# Group data by key with the groupBy operator rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

"rxjs": "7.8.0",

C сервера приходит Observable c таким значением:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "date": 1693229400000,
        "name": "event name",
        "impact": "Low",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "date": 1693229400000,
        "name": "event name",
        "impact": "Low",
    },    
    {
        "id": 3,
        "date": 1693229400000,
        "name": "event name",
        "impact": "Middle",
    }
]
```

Я хочу сгруппировать ответ по полю impact. Но код ниже ничего не возвращает, но и ошибка не падает. console.log не выводится.

```
events$ = this.onSubmit.pipe(
    switchMap((dateRange) => this.eventService.getEvents())
  ).pipe(
    mergeMap(res => res),
    groupBy(i => i.impact),
    mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray())),
  ).subscribe(res => console.log('RESULT', res));
```

Comment: *Я хочу сгруппировать ответ по полю impact.* Ну, допустим, сгруппировал. Первые 2 записи собрались в одну группу. Теперь надо разобраться с остальными полями... вот скажем `id` - значений два, а надо вывести одно (запись-то итоговая для группы одна). Вопрос - какое именно? почему? В написанном коде про это ни полслова. А программа - она дура и инициативы проявлять не будет, ей проще выдать ошибку. Что она и делает.

Comment: Заголовки стоит писать по-русски

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю, то в Observable приходят события с массивами объектов, и собственно вы хотите сгруппировать именно объекты этого массива.

groupBy от rxjs группирует именно события в Observable

Подошло если бы вам приходило по одному объекту за событие:

Для примера я сунул ваш массив в from() (что породит события на каждый элемент), данный код должен отработать

```
from([
    {
        "id": 1,
        "date": 1693229400000,
        "name": "event name",
        "impact": "Low",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "date": 1693229400000,
        "name": "event name",
        "impact": "Low",
    },    
    {
        "id": 3,
        "date": 1693229400000,
        "name": "event name",
        "impact": "Middle",
    }
])
.pipe(
    mergeMap(res => res),
    groupBy(i => i.impact),
    mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray())),
  ).subscribe(res => console.log('RESULT', res));
```

Существует решение для вас https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy но у него почти нет поддержки, рекомендую воспользоваться Array.reduce()

Пример (грязный):

```
res.reduce((acc, next) => {
  if (!acc[next.impact]) {
    acc[next.impact] = [];
  }
  acc[next.impact].push(next);
  return acc;
}, {});
```